# how to get file changed timestamp in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

As title, with NSFileManager I can get file creation time and modification time, while what I need is last changed time. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't "modification time" and "last changed time" the same thing? :-)

Comment: @MattR - nope, which might be surprising... (see my answer)

Comment: @CRD OK thanks, I hadn't considered status changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I use the following method.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

long lastChangedTimestamp = 0;
struct stat fileStatus;
if(0 == stat(filename, &fileStatus))
{
    lastChangedTimestamp = fileStatus.st_ctimespec.tv_sec;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to do this sort of things in cocoa is to use an NSURL.

You probably want to use fileURLWithPath:isDirectory: or fileURLWithPath: to create the the NSURL instance and then use getResourceValue:forKey:error: or resourceValuesForKeys:error: methods to get your resource values.

The resource keys to use for the timestamps are NSURLAttributeModificationDateKey, NSURLContentAccessDateKey, NSURLContentModificationDateKey and NSURLCreationDateKey.

Comment: Probably not an issue for most, but `NSURLAttributeModificationDateKey` is only available from 10.6

Answer (score 1):

Given you know that there is such a thing as the last status change time why not just use stat(2)? Or have I misunderstood the question?

stat(2) will give you all the times; creation, modification, accessed & metadata changed; it's not high-level, but trivial to call.

Comment: yes, with stat we can get all these time, while what I need is to use cocoa to get last changed time. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank - why do you *need* to use Cocoa? You can call stat(2) directly from Obj-C - Cocoa is just a library, stat(2) is just in another library...